# Trying to install my Wireless adapter RTL8812AU

Tags: 16.04

I'm getting an error when running the provided install.sh (sudo ./install.sh):

```
##################################################
Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0
##################################################
```

***I removed some logs in between here which are about decompressing the tar file.***

```
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal/led ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd platform ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/build M=/home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/include/drv_types.h:95:0,
                 from /home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/include/hal_com.h:412:13: error: ‘file_path’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 extern char file_path[PATH_LENGTH_MAX];
             ^
In file included from ./include/linux/seq_file.h:10:0,
                 from ./include/linux/pinctrl/consumer.h:17,
                 from ./include/linux/pinctrl/devinfo.h:21,
                 from ./include/linux/device.h:24,
                 from ./include/linux/dmaengine.h:20,
                 from ./include/linux/netdevice.h:38,
                 from /home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/include/osdep_service_linux.h:35,
                 from /home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/include/osdep_service.h:41,
                 from /home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/include/drv_types.h:32,
                 from /home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
./include/linux/fs.h:2680:14: note: previous declaration of ‘file_path’ was here
 extern char *file_path(struct file *, char *, int);
              ^
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/swift/Desktop/Linux/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic'
Makefile:1622: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

Comment: the make script is too old for the 4.10 headers. try to find a newer version.

Comment: Should I just manually install it by make and install?

Comment: make is what is giving the error

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

Reboot.

Comment: I think i got it to work. Here's what iwconifg gave me:
`enx000f0037b844  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0`
I'm trying to get monitor mode. Does this driver support monitor mode? Because I get an error.

Comment: Not all hardware and driver combinations support monitor mode. You can find out with: `iw list` If monitor mode is supported, it will report, in part: "Supported interface modes: * monitor"

Answer (score 0):

I found this gord-rtl8812au-dkms_1.0-9_amd64.deb working fine on 16.04.3-64. I suggest Ubuntu checking this and replace the 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu2 which drops line terribly.
https://github.com/MilhouseVH/rtl8812au-1/blob/master/gord-rtl8812au-dkms_1.0-9_amd64.deb