# How to install ASUS USB-AC56R on Ubuntu 20.04 (newbie)

Tags: command-line, drivers, usb, asus, usb-installation

I'm trying to install an ASUS USB-AC56R wifi wireless adapter in Ubuntu 20.04, but I don't know how to install the drivers. I have a "Linux" folder in the installation cd, with a zip file (RTL8812AU_linux_v4.2.5_10143.20140103_ASUS). I extracted it on my Downloads folder, and there is a tar.gz file inside with the same name. I just don't know how to go from there. I guess I have to install it using the terminal, but I haven't been able to figure out how, so I would need a step by step guide for newbies. Thank you very much in advance for your help

Comment: a tar.gz file is just like a zip file extract it

Comment: I just downloaded the driver from asus website after unzipping the second zip file there is  a readme.txt and an install.sh file run the install.sh file

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried to run the install.sh file, but I keep having this error: "Compile make driver error".
I tried several options:
chmod +x install.sh, and then
sudo bash install.sh, or
sudo ./install.sh, or
sh install.sh
None of them worked.

Comment: So I finally found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/981057/trying-to-install-my-wireless-adapter-rtl8812au. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After trying to run the install.sh file, and getting this error: "Compile make driver error", I finally found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/981057/trying-to-install-my-wireless-adapter-rtl8812au), given by [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555), and changing "rtl8812au -v 4.2.2" by "rtl8812au -v 4.2.5" (my version):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.5
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.5
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.5
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.5
```